# Capture all occurrences of repeated formatted substrings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've a string that follows this pattern `[:it]Stringa in italiano[:en]String in english`.

I'm trying to use `preg_match_all()` to capture the locales and the associated strings, ie:

```
[1] => 'it',
[2] => 'en',
...
[1] => 'Stringa in italiano',
[2] => 'String in english'
```

The regex that I'm using `"/\[:(\w+)](.+?)(?=\[:\w+])/"` (https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/400) returns only the first group of data. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need end of string i.e. `$`..`\[:(\w+)\](.+?)(?=\[:\w+\]|$)` .. https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/401

Comment: You can use a `preg_split` with `\[:(\w+)\]` and `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`  flag. It might be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The final formatted segment will not satisfy your lookahead.  You will need to include the option of match the position of the end of the string with an alternation.  A pipe (`|`) means "or". A dollar symbol (`$`) means "end of string".

I am using negated character classes to match between literal square braces.  If your `\w` is sufficient for your project, feel free to keep that portion as you originally posted.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P0Qvh))

```
$string = '[:it]Stringa in italiano[:en]String in english';

preg_match_all('~\[:([^]]+)](.+?)(?=$|\[:[^]]+])~', $string, $m);
var_export($m);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '[:it]Stringa in italiano',
    1 => '[:en]String in english',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'it',
    1 => 'en',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Stringa in italiano',
    1 => 'String in english',
  ),
)
```